# What is the best way of i18n in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization

I'm developing a website that's multilanguage. There are lots of solutions for example with database, .mo files, static php files etc. But what is the best way? Please can you give advice? Thanks..

Comment: Does CodeIgniter really bundle all those i18n solutions?

Comment: It's using static php files which contains $lang[] array. should be more good solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go for [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/). As it is a de-facto standard and is used in many applications in different languages. Many people use it means bigger community and good support.

If you search for gettext in stackoverflow, you'll get good resources and examples.

Getting started with it in PHP:
http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html

Comment: I thing this is good solution. So must I use database for multilanguage dynamic content? Or use gettext against?

Comment: I suggest you just stick with the standard `.mo` and `.po` files to make things simple and straightforward.


It will be easier for you to work with third-party translation services (non-techie translators). Just send them the text files, let them update and return the translated files back to you. 


Whereas if you use the database - you'll need to export, extract, import, etc. again which I think is too much of an effort. Unless maybe if your translators can have db access and knows SQL. But still `.mo` and `.po` files would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As Ardy said, Gettext is a good solution and has [native integration with php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), you could combine with [intl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php) for Internazionalization.

Another alternative is the Zend Framework 2 module I18n, but has dependencies with other ZF2 modules.